# How could i open two url with one hyperlink click

Tags: html

How could i put two urls to be opened in two different tab as a hyperlinks with one click on the text on wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a>
```

Please note this will not work if pop-up are disabled - the most you will get is one window. For testing disale your popup blocker in your browser. Note that site visitors who have popups enabled will not see both urls open.